# When to include apostrophe in clojure require?

Tags: syntax, clojure

What is the difference between:

```
(require '[some-package.sub as some])
(require 'example.core)
```

and

```
(require [some-package.sub as some])
(require example.core)
```

When should I use one over the other? Only the one with apostrophe works in an REPL environment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [clojure require syntax rationale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819591/clojure-require-syntax-rationale)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`require` is a function (check with `(source require)` in a REPL). Thus is evaluates its parameters before its own evaluation.

At the time you call require the symbol `some-package.sub` resolves `(points)` to nothing, so you get a *"Unable to resolve symbol: `the-symbol-that-points-to-nothing` in this context...*"

However, if you quote the said symbol we can get to the actual evaluation of `require`. Thus `require`, since it is a function, necessitates quoted forms.

Now `ns` is a macro (check with `(source ns)` in a REPL). Thus is doesn't evaluate its parameters before expansion. Technically it could take free symbols or quoted forms but it was decided to use raw free symbols. `(ns lalala (:require [some-package.sub :as some]))`

No-o-o-o-ow, when you call `require` (function) with `a`, you will actually require the symbol which is held by the var which a resolves to.

#### Example:

```
(def a 'B)
(require a)
FileNotFoundException Could not locate B__init.c;ass or B.clj on the classpath[...]
```

...that's because require is a function.

Hope it helped.